# Refer to defined variable from function outside Python class

Tags: python, django

Excuse for newbie question but I want make all clear for myself. I have a problem accessing class variable from within function outside the class. In code below I need **`text, text2`**. I get variables as tuple but I need them separately. How to update code to get defined variable like **`text = var1`** and **`text2 = var2`**? Thanks in advance!

```
from django.shortcuts import render

class Someclass():
    def method_1(self):
        self.var2 = 'var2'
        self.var1 = 'var1'
        return self.var1 ,self.var2

def func(request):
    cls = Someclass()
    text2 = cls.method_1()
    text = cls.method_1()
    content = {
        'text': text,
        'text2': text2,
    }
    return render(request, "web/page.html", content)
```

Comment: Thanks for editing and please ask how to point out text with grey background?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `tuple unpacking` - you can return several results, and receive several results from a func

```
text, text2 = cls.method_1()
```

Also you better not name your variables text and text2. And also `cls` is a common word to use for a class, and in your code `cls` is an instance, that's a bit unpythonic :)

Comment: Thanks! But how to make it more 'pythonic'? :)

Comment: Make the name mean something. Like if you have `class Parser()`  then `parser = Parser()` or `facebook_parser = FacebookParser(args)`. Same goes for `text` and `text2`. Or at least name it `obj` - not `cls` :)

Answer (score 3):

Since you are returning a tuple you should directly assign their values to variables in a single call.

Something like this:

```
text, text2 = cls.method_1()
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:
  text2 = cls.method_1()
  text = cls.method_1()

do:
  text2, text = cls.method_1()